# WCF Service Access right: No access rights to this namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, http

I'm getting the the following error while running my program with the task scheduler:

> HTTP could not register URL http://+:4711/myWCFService/. Your
>   process does not have access rights to this namespace (see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). --->
>   System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied

Run as administrator is unfortunately no solution for my problem. I also tried to register the http address with netsh but I'm getting still the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `netsh` command did you run?

```
netsh http add urlacl http://+:4711/ user=DOMAIN\USER
```

On your machine, the built-in administrator account has implicit ownership of all HTTP namespace reservations, so you need to delegate ownership of the specific namespace reservation (like above) to the target account that will be running the HTTP endpoint. You do this by ensuring you `Run as administrator` before performing the `netsh` command.

To check what namespace reservations are in place, run:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

Comment: Are there any security concerns for allowing this? We have a vendor who wants to delegate a service account this way?  I would much rather the vendor make the service run under Local System but they are unable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a test WFC service hosted in Windows Service (Managed). Then I added another base address for HTTP. When I started the service again, I got the same error. I then changed the service account from "Local Service" to "Local System" and that resolved the issue. Since this was a test program, it was OK for me to continue.